# Knockout render checkboxes using foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

it is my firs experience with `knockout`. I cannot find how to render list of checkboxes using `foreach`.

what I tried:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" data-bind="foreach: placeCategories">
    <label class="col-sm-6" data-bind="text: name">
         <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: val">
    </label>
</div>
```

But I get only name, without check box. Probably label inner html is overwritten. But how to show also check box and text both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html):

> The `text` binding sets the content to a text node with your parameter value. Any previous content will be overwritten.

So you need to use the `text` binding on a different element e.g on a `span`

```
<div class="col-sm-12" data-bind="foreach: placeCategories">
    <label class="col-sm-6"> 
         <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
         <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: val">
    </label>
</div>
```

Or you can also use the containerless syntax:

```
<div class="col-sm-12" data-bind="foreach: placeCategories">
    <label class="col-sm-6"> 
         <!--ko text: name--><!--/ko-->
         <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: val">
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you helped with ko comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use ko comment tags or multiple sub-elements (eg. spans) in order to avoid your bindings overwriting one another.

Just for fun, you *CAN* overwrite the Knockout `text` binding to allow this kind of behavior. The code below will test the element's content for `data-bind` attributes, and in case it finds any, insert the text-node at the beginning of the element, while maintaining the other bindings.

```js
var app = {
  placeCategories: [
    {name: ko.observable('A'), val: ko.observable(false)},
    {name: ko.observable('B'), val: ko.observable(false)},
    {name: ko.observable('C'), val: ko.observable(false)}
  ]
};

ko.bindingHandlers.text.update = function(element, valueAccessor) {
   var hasBindings = element.innerHTML.match('data-bind'),
       value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
  
   if (hasBindings) {
     if (element.firstChild.nodeType !== 3)
       element.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(' '), element.firstChild);
     element.firstChild.nodeValue = value;
   } else
     element.nodeValue = value;
};

ko.applyBindings(app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12" data-bind="foreach: placeCategories">
    <label class="col-sm-6" data-bind="text: name">
         <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: val">
    </label>
</div>
```

Note: I wouldn't encourage to do this, but it's possible. I would rather create a new custom binding to allow it.

Comment: nice to know that I can overwrite bindings, but it too complicated for my paticular task.

Comment: @Edgar, NP I know, it was just a curiosity I wanted to investigate :)